# ng repeat and scroll down and up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm made a table with  and i'm trying to add a feature that allow user when scroll mouse down adds more rows but also to have fixed number of rows and vise verse correct when scroll up .
i'm using javascript angular
but now when i add information to field in a row and scroll down all information that was in the row disappear .
how could i when scroll down save the information .
my html code :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive col-md-11" ng-mouse-wheel-up="myscrollup()" ng-mouse-wheel-down="myscrolldown()" style="width: 95%">
                <thead >

                <tr context-menu="otherMenuOptions">
                    <th style="background-color: #00aba9" ng-style="colwidth[$index]" ng-repeat="h in head track by $index" >


                        <a style="color:#fff" href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'field{{$index}}'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                            {{h}}

                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'field{{$index}}' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'field{{$index}}' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-angle-up"></span>

                        </a>
                    </th>

                </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody >
                <tr  ng-repeat="i in getNumber(NOR) track by $index | filter : $index>=RSN">
                <td >  {{$index+1}}</td>
                   <td> <input ng-style="name[$index]" ng-model="test" type="" value=""> </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" value=""> </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" value=""> </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" value=""> </td>
                   <td> <input type="text" value=""> </td>
                   <td> <input type="date" value=""> </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and my functions

```
$scope.myscrolldown=function(){
        $scope.RSN++;
        $scope.NOR++;
    };
    $scope.myscrollup=function(){
        $scope.RSN--;
    };
```

Comment: In your controller where you add the table row, use $scope.$apply();

Comment: i don't understand you.